# How to use converted tensorflow model.json file in angular for live object detection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have Python converted models.json but how to detect objects using this model for the  web-cam  in angular

```js
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

export class MyComponent {
   @ViewChild('videoElement') videoElement: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('canvasElement') canvasElement: ElementRef;

  private model: tf.GraphModel;
  private requestAnimationFrameId: number;

  constructor() {
    this.loadModel();
  }

  async loadModel() {
    this.model = await tf.loadGraphModel('assets/model.json');
  }

  async startDetection() {
    await this.setupCamera();
    this.detectFrame();
  }

  async setupCamera() {
    const video = this.videoElement.nativeElement;
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
    video.srcObject = stream;
    await video.play();
  }

  detectFrame() {
    const video = this.videoElement.nativeElement;
    const canvas = this.canvasElement.nativeElement;
    canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    const inputTensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(imageData).expandDims();
    const outputTensor = this.model.executeAsync(inputTensor);
    outputTensor.then(results => {
      console.log('Detection results:', results);
      this.drawBoundingBoxes(context, results);
      this.requestAnimationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(() => this.detectFrame());
    });
  }

  drawBoundingBoxes(context, results) {
    const boxes = results[0].dataSync();
    const scores = results[1].dataSync();
    const classes = results[2].dataSync();
    const numDetections = results[3].dataSync()[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < numDetections; i++) {
      const boxOffset = i * 4;
      const scoreOffset = i;
      const classOffset = i;
      const yMin = boxes[boxOffset] * context.canvas.height;
      const xMin = boxes[boxOffset + 1] * context.canvas.width;
      const yMax = boxes[boxOffset + 2] * context.canvas.height;
      const xMax = boxes[boxOffset + 3] * context.canvas.width;
      const score = scores[scoreOffset];
      const cls = classes[classOffset];
      if (score > 0.5) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(xMin, yMin, xMax - xMin, yMax - yMin);
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        context.strokeStyle = 'green';
        context.stroke();
        context.fillStyle = 'green';
        context.fillText(`${cls} (${score.toFixed(2)})`, xMin, yMin - 10);
      }
    }
  }

  stopDetection() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.requestAnimationFrameId);
    const video = this.videoElement.nativeElement;
    video.pause();
    video.srcObject.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
  }
```

Can I Use multiple model.json in the same project? if yes then how to do that.

problem is how to **detect Frame** of an object and draws the **Bounding Boxes** around an object and I do not know how to do that. If anyone has an idea let me know.

in the console, in input got the tensor shape but how to convert it to the output?